# Google Cloud Storage - how to authorize?

Tags: java, api, cloud, storage, google-cloud-storage

I am desperately trying to access Google Cloud Storage from Java. My challenge is that I should create a generic library and a browser based auth is not possible.

Whatever I do, it always tells me "401 Unauthorised". I am definitely using the correct credentials, ... My Java Version is 1.7

Here is the code:

```
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
            .setClientSecrets("clientid", "clientsecret").build();

            storage = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
                "test-name")
                .build();
```

The corresponding client id and secret is set as shown in the console; however, I always tells me "Login required". The library needs to be used from a worker process, so it is impossible that someone authorises the application in a browser window ...

Thanks,

Mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that just recently we discussed in person that this problem is actually solved by using Google Service accounts as documented over here:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

The credentials are the built like this:

```
String emailAddress = "123456789000-abc123def456@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("MyProject.p12"))
    .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(SQLAdminScopes.SQLSERVICE_ADMIN))
    .build();
```